# custom 503 error page thrown from servlet java

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic-10.x, http-status-code-503

This is pretty simple and straightforward. I want to throw a 503 error from the servlet side.

```
response.sendError(503);
```

When this is thrown, I need it to hit a custom error page. Basically a 503 error page itself, but with a few modifications.

Say I have `503.html`, and I added

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/503.html</location>
</error-page>
```

in `web.xml`.

I created a war file, with a servlet which throws the 503 error, and `web.xml` with this content.  I kept the `503.html` in the parent folder location. (Should I keep it elsewhere ?)

I deployed the app in WLS, but this custom `503.html` is not getting hit. I am getting the generic 503 error.

Am I missing something?

My code is below:

webapp1.war

> ->web-inf
>
> ->web-inf->classes->prject4->Class1.class
>
> ->web-inf->jsp->error->custom.html

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

     <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Class1</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>project2.Class1</servlet-class>
   </servlet>   

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Class1</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/custom.html</location>
</error-page>

</web-app>
```

class1.java

```
public class Class1 extends HttpServlet
{   
  private ServletConfig config;

  public void init(ServletConfig config)throws ServletException
  {
   this.config=config;
  }

   public void service (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException
   {

     response.setContentType("text/html");     
     ServletOutputStream l_out = response.getOutputStream();     

     response.sendError(503); 
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parent folder location"? if you configured it as "/503.html" you should put the html page right under the root folder.

Comment: @didxga yes the /503.html is kept right at the root folder, along side with WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Please draw out your file structure.

Comment: @didxga modified the question.

Comment: @Tom are you using WL as application server with another web server?

Comment: no , am using wls as the server. deploying apps into a managed server directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was a minor error which I didn't figure out in the beginning.

In my `web.xml` the servlet-mapping was given as `/*`, which was causing an infinite loop condition as it throws the same code for which it has been mapped. So I had to adjust the servlet mapping so that `Class1` doesn't map to any error pages - like say `/images/*`.

And then everything started working fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven as your project build tool then it will look in the src/main/webapp directory, so for example our config looks like this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/error404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

and our error404.html sits in the folder:

${PROJECT_NAME}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/error/

If your not using Maven the path in the location will have a base directory of wherever you put your index.jsp

Comment: no am not using maven , i just used jar command in java sdk .

Comment: modified the question with more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try handling it with custom Error Handler.

```
public void service (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException
 {
      try
      {
          //some error generating code
           throw new Exception("503_Exception");
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          response.sendRedirect(HandleError.handle(e, request));
      }
 }
```

A separate class to handle errors. This can handle different types of errors.
You can add functionality to log stacktrace, send out emails if something is wrong etc.

```
public class HandleError{
    public static String handle(Throwable t, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
    { 
         String sErrorMsg = t.getMessage();

         if (sErrorMsg.equals("503_Exception")) {
            request.setAttribute("msg", Constants.EINVALSESSION);
            return "/503.html";
         }


         return "/default_error.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: i keep getting page not found 404 error . I am returning "/WEB-INF/jsp/error/custom.html" . Its gets redirected to that location , but i get Error 404--Not Found . any idea ?

Comment: @Tom Is there a reason why you have placed the html file inside the "WEB-INF" folder?
When you place the jsp within the WEB-INF folder you cannot access the JSP directly.
To access it you will have to create a servlet entry in the web.xml which will map you to a particular jsp.
I wold suggest to you place it outside WEB-INF so you can access it directly. In my example, "503.html" and "default_error.html" are placed directly outside "WEB-INF".

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's a minimum limit on the number bytes your custom error page has. The lower limit is usually 512 Bytes. See [Important note for your Custom error pages](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/21/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/). I've seen this behavior in Google-Chrome too when using Tomcat.

Comment: I am using FF. And my custom.html is of 1388 bytes.

Comment: @Tom, then i guess it has something to do with the page location specified in your web.xml, although it looks fine.

Comment: @Tom, try rearrange your structure this way: webapp1.war-->jsp-->error-->custom.html, then change the configuration of location to /jsp/error/custom.html. although your way seems right

Comment: @Tom what do logs say? I've not used WL, but Tomcat has an access log printing the way, each files are accessed, in the format `%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b`. If the status code is 404 when it's using the custom error page, it means it couldn't find your page and the browser showed its default. More @ [tomcat 5.5 reference docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html)